Outdated state when using function reference instead of lambda in compose
@Composable
fun App() {
    var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Column {
        Button(onClick = { count++ }) {
            Text("Counter: $count")
        }
        Child(count)
    }
}

@Composable
fun Child(count: Int) {
    fun onClick() {
        println("Current counter: $count")
    }

    Column {
        Button(onClick = { onClick() }) {
            Text("Print with lambda")
        }
        Button(onClick = ::onClick) {
            Text("Print with function reference")
        }
    }
}

After pressing the counter button at least once, the behavior of the two print buttons is different. The "Print with lambda" button prints the current counter while the "Print with function reference" button always prints the initial state 0.
This feels really unintuitive. Is this intended and if yes, is there any documentation that describes this behavior?

this feels like a bug that should be reported to the compose team

I just tested it on Compose 1.7.0-beta05 and there, both buttons were always printing the same number. Which Kotlin and Compose version are you on and are you testing on multiplatform or in Android Studio?

it's probably already fixed then. I tested with multiplatform 1.6.11 which should be based on 1.6.7

I had tested it on the latest stable version of multiplatform (1.6.11) but could also reproduce on a new android project with compose 1.6.6. Upgrading to multiplatform 1.7.0-alpha03 does indeed fix the problem for me. Thanks for letting me know :)

As BenjyTec has pointed out, this behavior has been fixed in Compose 1.7.0.
